# Kotlin inheritance simply

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

can someone explain to me how **inheritance** works in **Kotlin** ? I struggle with Kotlin's inheritance and seem to be unable to achieve easy tasks I know in Java.

In Java we could have something like this :

```
class Base {...}
class AClass extends Base {...}
class BClass extends Base {...}
```

and a service doing so :

```
Base myMethod(...) {
    return new AClass() //or new BClass()
}
```

because AClass is a Base, and BClass is a Base too.

When I try the same in Kotlin, I've got an error message telling that a Base object is expected where I try to return AClass or BClass objects.

> Type mismatch. Required: Base Found: AClass?

So what is the Kotlin's way to realize simple things like this ?

---

Edit : Kotlin classes

```
sealed class GameObject {
    abstract val objectId: String
    abstract val objectName: String
}


sealed class Resource(
    override val objectId: String,
    override val objectName: String,
    open val resourceType : ResourceType
): GameObject() {
    abstract val usageEffects: List<UseEffect>
    abstract val eolEffects: List<DiscardEffect>
    abstract val recipes: List<Recipe>
    abstract val providedEnergy: Int
    abstract val neededEnergy: Int
}


data class BaseResource(
    override val resourceType: ResourceType,
    override val usageEffects: List<UseEffect> = emptyList(),
    override val eolEffects: List<DiscardEffect> = emptyList(),
    override val recipes: List<Recipe> = emptyList(),
    override val providedEnergy: Int = 0,
    override val neededEnergy: Int = 0,
): Resource("RES", "RES", resourceType)


data class ProductionFactor(
    override val resourceType: ResourceType,
    override val usageEffects: List<UseEffect> = emptyList(),
    override val eolEffects: List<DiscardEffect> = emptyList(),
    override val recipes: List<Recipe> = emptyList(),
    val productivity: Int = 1,
    override val providedEnergy: Int = 0,
    override val neededEnergy: Int = 0,
    val combustibleTypes: List<ResourceType> = emptyList()
    var combustibles: List<Resource> = mutableListOf()
): Resource("RES", "RES", resourceType)
```

These are some of the objects I struggle with.

Now the use case : all 'Resource' objects (both BaseResource and ProductionFactor) are stored in this map :

```
var resourcesMap: EnumMap<ResourceType, out Resource>
```

Depending on events, I want to return a copy of the Resource object stored as the 'value' in this map (against the ResourceType which is the 'key') :

```kotlin
fun getCard(card: Card): GameObject? {

    var gameObject: GameObject? = null
    val type = card.cardType
    when (type) {
        CardType.TERRITORY -> {
            val territoryCard = card as TerritoryCard
            val territoryType = territoryCard.territory
            gameObject = territoriesMap[territoryType]?.copy(objectId = card.cardId, objectName = card.cardName)
        }
        CardType.RESOURCE -> {
            val resourceCard = card as ResourceCard
            val resourceType = resourceCard.resource
            when (val resource = resourcesMap[resourceType]) {
                is BaseResource -> {
                    gameObject = resource.copy(objectId = card.cardId, objectName = card.cardName)
                }
                is ProductionFactor -> {
                    gameObject = resource.copy(objectId = card.cardId, objectName = card.cardName)
                }

                null -> println("Unknown type")
            }
        }
        CardType.BUILDING -> {
            val buildingCard = card as BuildingCard
            val buildingType = buildingCard.building
            gameObject = buildingsMap[buildingType]?.copy(objectId = card.cardId, objectName = card.cardName)
        }
    }

    return gameObject
}
```

Comment: We need to see your actual code. From the error message it looks like you're trying to return a nullable type somehow. Nullable versions of types are supertypes, not subtypes, of the type they're based on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Type mismatch. Required: Base Found: AClass?

The reason is that even if `AClass` is a subtype of `Base`, `AClass?` is *not* a subtype of `Base`, because `AClass?` contains `null` in its subset of values but `Base` doesn't.

`resourcesMap.get(...)` (or `resourcesMap[...]`) return `Resource?` that cannot be assigned to `Resource`. If you want to assign this expression to a non-nullable variable, right after the assignment you can (besides `!!` that may lead to a crash) use  `?: return ...` or  `?: throw ...` depending on the logic relevant to your case

Comment: When retrieving a value from a Map that you assert will be present and therefore not null, the idiomatic way is to use the `map.getValue()` function, which will throw an appropriate error with a specific message if your assertion is wrong.